# How to retrieve video rotation degree before API 17?

Tags: android, video, metadata, exif

I want to get video rotation information and find that I can read METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION string  using MediaMetadataRetriever.But METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION macro is only supported by API level 17+.

Is there another method to get video rotation information?Thanks.